# Counting Twins-primes with AKS primality test in C++ What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, math, gcc, codeblocks, primes

Good night, I'm not a C++ especialist. I need to count the quantity of twin-primes inside 3 and the limit. My output is always giving 1. What am I doing wrong? Here's my algorithm with AKS working as well!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long long c[100];

void coef(int n)
{
    c[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; c[0] = -c[0], i++) {
        c[1 + i] = 1;

        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
            c[j] = c[j - 1] - c[j];
    }
}

bool isPrime(int n)
{

    coef(n);


    c[0]++, c[n]--;


    int i = n;
    while (i-- && c[i] % n == 0)
        ;


    return i < 0;
}

int main()
{
    int limit=10000,counter=1,i;
    for(i=3;i<=limit;i+=2){
    if (isPrime(i)){

        if(isPrime(i+2)){
                counter++;
    }
 }
}
cout <<counter;
return 0;
}
```

I'm on codeblocks 17.02 on Windows 10 Pro. What's the stupidity am I doing?

Comment: You are looking at c[n] where n > sizeof(c)

Comment: The AKS implementation isn't mine, and I tested it before, it was working well. I don't understood it.

Comment: That was just the first place I crashed. You define a function called coef which you do not use. Just looking at the logic in main, why would you only count the lower prime in the pair?

Comment: try this:  if (isPrime(i)){ std::cout << i << "is prime." << std::endl; ... You will see that isPrime believes there are no prime numbers. (This is after I changed the size of c to accommodate the hardcoded limit which does not match the size of c.)

Comment: Sorry, for my copy/pasta error. coef() is now correct utilized and I can't get the result yet.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Fixed code! I had a issues copying/pasting but I still can't count the twin-primes

Comment: Your isPrime function now correctly finds odd primes up to and including 61, but it doesn't find any more, ever.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Great.

Comment: How many twin primes do you find now?

Comment: Never use <bits/stdc++.h>, nonstandard. "using namespace std" is lazy but okay -- I always type out std::cout. TEST your functions -- isPrime doesn't do what you think it does. You have a logic error counting twin primes, which you can illustrate by setting the upper bound at 10. looking at the primes "3, 5, 7" There are three there, but you count 2 twin primes. referencing and changing the array "c" outside of its defined size is undefined behavior.

Comment: also note that isPrime has side effects. I think it only works if you check numbers in a specific pattern, which I have not been able to find. (if it works at all)

Comment: This looks like the same method of finding primes, at the bottom https://helloacm.com/c-coding-exercise-count-primes/  You just need to modify the count to look for twin primes. Remember that both twins are twin primes, but only count them once.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't at **all** the AKS algorithm for primality.  It looks like a slightly modified version of the [RosettaCode task](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/AKS_test_for_primes#C) which implements the exponential time lemma.  It will be slower than simple trial division, not to mention that without modular arithmetic this implementation is basically useless since it will overflow on even toy size inputs.

Once you have a proper primality test, one thing to consider would be not calling isprime() on the same inputs over and over.  You can call it once per number and just remember the last prime you found.  If isprime(i) is true, then count if the last one you found was i-2.  Now you don't need repeated calls, nor an array of values.

Even better, since you want to generate all the primes to n, is to use a sieve.  It is much more efficient for that task than primality tests, even with much better primality tests.  You can find a trivial C version at the [RosettaCode page for that task](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  There are better ones out there, but that doesn't really matter here given what you're starting with.